# Can't change theme for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I tried installing a theme util from market place (Eclipse Color Theme 1.0.0) but I keep getting a confirm dialog and when I click it nothing happens. It says no repository found in git.
When I try to change it in preferences. It doesn't change I have dark on dark text currently and can't read it very well.
[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows the preferences for syntax coloring. Go to the preferences _General > Appearance_ instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just reset to default and got white background again. And found it using your hint. Post that with more details, good answer, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **screenshot shows** the preferences for the **syntax coloring themes** of [Eclipse TM4E](https://eclipse.org/tm4e), which is used for instance by [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) for JavaScript, XML, etc. mostly in combination with a language server for code completion. Those syntax coloring themes are shown in the *Generic Text Editor* in the right-click *Switch to theme* submenu.

The **UI theme** you are probably looking for can be selected in the **preferences *General > Appearance*** instead.